# caffe kernel died jupyter qtconsole

Tags: python, cluster-computing, caffe, jupyter-notebook

I run http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/01-learning-lenet.ipynb on jupyter notebook.

However, it pops the error: `kernel died`,  after I run the code

```
solver = caffe.SGDSolver('mnist/lenet_auto_solver.prototxt')
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got an answer. It is to add a line of code `solver_mode = GPU` at the end of the file `lenet_auto_solver.prototxt`.